How to deal with possibly important predictors omitted during the building of an OLS multivariate linear regression model?
I am building a descriptive model using OLS multivariate linear regression. I have a couple dozen candidate predictors, but only around 200 cases.
Since I wanted at least 10 cases / variable for the global model, I chose 20 variables, leaving the rest outside the model.
This global model was subjected to backwards stepwise variable selection, informed by leave-one-out cross-validation. The final model was re-fitted using all the complete cases in the sample.
I then was advised to plot the residuals on the values of each of the initially excluded variables. I found clear patterns in some of those plots. Which I interpret means that those variables are somewhat associated with the outcome or some of the predictors in the model.
I do not know what to do next. I have not been able to find a clear answer of how to deal with those omitted but relevant variables. In some cases, they have been just added to the model and compared to the previous model through some criterion (MSE, AIC), but those examples I have seen them only in the context of econometrics.
Somehow, it rubs me wrong. It seems too simple. Could anyone point me towards bibliography on this topic?

Update (31/05/2024)
Thank you for all the (worried) comments. I am updating here my original question with more complete context.
First, this is what I meant when speaking about patterns when plotting residuals on excluded variables:

And this is how I came to the situation that made me post the question:
I had been given a little observational research project on the association between an environmental exposure (mercury) and an "ecological" outcome (gut microbiota diversity).
From bibliographic search I identified around 40 different variables known to affect the outcome, many of them categorical with several levels.
DAGs were plotted for clarifying relationships, correlated variables were grouped when possible, levels in categorical variables were fused when reasonable.
I ruled out those variables that were poorly represented in our dataset (lots of missing values), or that were supposedly not important for the age range of our sample population (debatable but based in published research).
After all that, I still was left with more than twenty variables for a sample size of less than 200.
For each combination of exposure and outcome I built a model. I placed one variable (or dummy variable) into the model for each 10 cases in the sample size.
One problem here is that I knew that probably many of those variables introduced a lot of noise because:
Most of the previous studies have been made outside the age range I am studying (early infancy and adulthood, while I am studying adolescence).

Many of the variables are suppossed to have a weak effect anyway.

Many of the previous estudies built their models using p-values as the selection criterion.

Many of our mesures are noisy by their very nature (self-assessments through questionnaires).

Trying to boost signal over noise I decided to apply variable selection over these first global models.
My intention was to use best subset selection, with AIC as the selection criterion (more permissive than BIC).
I ended resorting to backwards stepwise selection because the leaps package does not work well with categorical variables, and the olsrr package can not force in more than one variable (it seems to be a bug). I eventually found a roundabout around it, but at that time I had already ran backwards selection over all the models.
So, I combined backwards stepwise selection with leave-one-out cross-validation and chose the variables that consistently resulted in the minimum AIC. In retrospect, the LOO-CV could have been an unnecesary complication.
As kind of a sensitivity analysis, I re-fitted the models adding to the sample some extra cases (~10% of sample size) that at first were left out for several reasons. There were no big changes in effect size nor intervals of the estimated coefficients.
The problem was that I was sure that, some of the variables that were not included in the initial global models, are in fact associated with the outcome; and I doubted if I could put them in the final model someway. Hence this question here in the subreddit. I guess my question was flawed from the beginning.
For those interested, most of my decisions for variable selection came from these sources:
Gareth, J. (2021) An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R. Chapter 6: Linear Model Selection and Regularization
Heinze, G. (2018) Variable selection - A review and recommendations for the practicing statistician

Greetings! It would be very illustrative to provide plots of these patterns, as "patterns" can mean many things with respect to residuals. I would also heavily advise against stepwise regression, for reasons that have been discussed here ad nauseum.

With a big reason being that stepwise regression affects downstream inferences (the test statistics you calculate do not have the claimed distribution, so their claimed p-values and confidence intervals are not correct, perhaps grossly so).

What is the goal of your analysis? Is it to remove confounding to estimate the effect of one variable? If not, why do you care if the predictor is correlated with the residual? If it is to build a predictive model, why did you both with linear regression instead of a more flexible method? Why didn't you use best practices in variable selection (e.g., lasso)?

@Noah The goal is to remove confounding in the estimated effect of an exposure variable. I did not use lasso because I think that it works the best when a few independent variables have a strong effect, which was not expected for my models. Rather, we expected that numerous variables would have a weak effect on the dependent variable. I wanted to use best subset selection to account for that kind of associations, but I could not at that time, so I fell back to backwards stepwise.

Things went very badly when you decided to do variable selection.  Start back from the beginning and pose a subject matter-informed completely pre-specified model.  Do unsupervised learning to reduce the dimensionality of the problem before doing this.  Details are here.
